# SQL fetch specific level parent in hierarchy table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table storing hierarchy details as below

```
id      parentid        Level
------------------------------
1       null            Unit1
2       1               Unit2
3       1               Unit2
4       1               Unit2
5       2               Unit3  
6       3               Unit3
7       4               Unit3
8       5               Unit4
9       6               Unit4
10      7               Unit4
11      7               Unit4
```

Need a sql to fetch the Unit3 parent of any given id. Basically, i need the result of query to show me

```
id      parentid        Level   Unit3Parent
-------------------------------------------
1       null            Unit1   null
2       1               Unit2   null
3       1               Unit2   null
4       1               Unit2   null
5       2               Unit3   2
6       3               Unit3   3
7       4               Unit3   4
8       5               Unit4   2
9       6               Unit4   3
10      7               Unit4   4
11      7               Unit4   4
```

Note that the unit3Parent column always shows either 2,3 or 4 - only .

Comment: Have you tried any solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create function fnGetParent(@ID int)
returns int
as
begin
declare @p as int
  Select @p=t.parentID from table1 t where t.ID=@ID
  if @p>4 
  begin
  set @p= fnGetParent(@p)
  end  
  return @p 
end


select a.*, fnGetParent(a.ID) unit3parent
from table1 a
order by a.ID asc
```

Comment: It works on my DB. I could't build an example in SQLFiddle to test it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6

Comment: Yes, i tried something similar. Except that fnGetParent gets another parameter say //@level such that you can have a condition //@p> @level.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the result using the following query. The recursion query keeps a track of the heirarchical level. If the level is 1, then return null, if level is 2 then return the parent id it self, if the level is 3 then return the parent's parent.

```
WITH parents(id,parentid,level,unit3level,unit3parent)
AS
(
   SELECT id,parentid,level,1,NULL 
   FROM tableName WHERE parentid IS NULL

   UNION ALL

   SELECT t.id,t.parentid,t.level, p.unit3level + 1, 
          CASE p.unit3level     WHEN  3 THEN p.parentid 
                                WHEN  2 THEN t.parentid
                                ELSE NULL END
   FROM tableName t JOIN parents p ON t.parentid = p.id

)
SELECT id,parentid,level,unit3parent
FROM parents;
```